# sifr3 disappears when I click "add to cart"

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart, sifr3

Anyone have any experience with why this happens:

sIFR 3 runs fine til I click add to cart and I get a javascript notification that it's been added to the cart. Upon click, the sIFR text disappears: http://loadedgranola.valitics.com/_product_83484/blackberry_lime. Try it out and let me know if their is something wrong with wht I'm doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `AddToCart` is replacing most of the page with the result of the AJAX call, so the Flash objects that sIFR created are obliterated.

So, I'd say your options are:

1. Prevent the page content from being replaced (may not be easy depending on your shopping cart framework).
2. Re-apply sIFR to the page after the content has been replaced.  You may need to use [rollback](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Add-ons) before re-applying sIFR.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have to direct access to the ajax or asp.net framework of the site, so sifr has been canned for now. Thanks!